# How to split values in the command line for Java?

Tags: java, input, command-line

My program uses the command line to take in the amount of people and days to help run a simulation. '-p' represents people and '-d' represents days. I'm supposed to have it so the program takes the two numbers and uses them for their respective purposes. My issue is figuring out how to turn the String values into integers and then picking out the numbers so I can use them. Also, if one or the other isn't typed, there should be a default value of 5 for people and 31 for days. If the users doesn't put in a correct input it should tell them how to do so. I need help getting the values from the user, setting default values, and informing them if there's an incorrect input. This is how the command line should look for both cases of correct input and incorrect input:

Correct: (ignore the java MarketSim part)

java MarketSim

java MarketSim -p 4

java MarketSim -d 22345

java MarketSim -d 5 -p 3

Incorrect:

java MarketSim -p

java MarketSim -d

java MarketSim -d 5 -p

java MarketSim -d 4 -p 4 -c

java MarketSim -zxvf

Message for correct input:
[image]

Comment: I have it printing out "java MarketSim" and then using Scanner to input the values. I use nextLine() to get them both and then turn them into integers with Integer.parseInt(). I'm not sure what to do afterwards.

Comment: if you have a try catch you can  output the error message on the catch

Comment: Are you using a Scanner to have the user interactively enter the values, or are you entering the values as part of the command line as your text shows?  If the latter, the values already exist, as the args array that is the argument to main().

Comment: @FredK I'm using Scanner, but I think I'm supposed to enter them as part of the command line. I just don't know how it works getting the value for p and value for d.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reinventing the wheel, there's a [Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/introduction.html) project in the Apache Commons project.  You basically define the options, use their parser and have access to a data structure to get particular options, or display help/usage information if the option doesn't match.